# What does this Gothic W symbol mean?

Tags: notation, lambert-w

What on earth does this symbol mean here, in [this article](https://www.uwo.ca/apmaths/faculty/jeffrey/pdfs/JeffreyJankowskiSYNASC2014.pdf):

$$\mathfrak{W}(xe^x)$$

After copying and pasting, I find it is supposedly a W, but clearly it has a certain meaning since the article refers to W (Lambert W) and to this symbol very differently, as if it were a constant perhaps, or some function.

Not knowing what the authors mean by this is completely compromising my ability to understand this article!

Comment: At a guess, they are distinguishing between the multi-branch function , $\mathfrak W$, and the branches, $W_k$.  I have no seen that notation before...people usually just write $W$ and $W_k$.  (to be sure:  my guess might not be correct).

Comment: Seems like they are using $\mathfrak{W}$ to denote the difference between two branches of the $W$ function.  It's bizarre how they never define it though.

Comment: @lulu I don't suppose you know what $\mathfrak{W}_{mn}$ means then?

Comment: @EricWofsey You either? If it is the multivalued function, then why do they subscript with branches as well - this confuses me

Comment: In section IV of the article, they write $\mathfrak{W}(z)=W_0(z)-W_{-1}(z)$ (they call this the principal difference).

Comment: In the proof of theorem 1, there is a step saying $\mathfrak{W}=W_m-W_n$, as in the difference between two branches, which is consistent with @projectilemotion's observation.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you!

Comment: Very bizarre to introduce and use the notation first, and then define it further on in the text.  But it appears that's what they have done.